# how to perform Click event in Gridview

Tags: asp.net

I have taken a Gridview and in Gridview I have taken an Image Button.

Now I want to perform click event on that Image Button.

How can I do that??

Tell me something about click events using Gridview.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind [RowCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx) event of gridView, You can not bind click event to button as you do with button not in GridView.

*GridView html*

```
<asp:GridView id="GridView1" Runat="server" OnRowCommand="GridViewCommandEventHandler" />
```

*Event handler*

```
void GridView1_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly create click event on that Image Button by double click on Image Button

Or Manually you can add

```
<asp:ImageButton id="ImageButton1" Runat="server" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click"/>
```

and in code behind file you can use

```
void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) 
{
   // you code here...
}
```